# How to set parameters on Groovy/Grails InvokeHelper.invokeMethod()

Tags: grails, groovy, spring-integration

I have a Grails webapp running a Spring Integration inbound-channel-adapter that is configured to receive emails and there is a service activator that processes the message. This service activator pulls out pieces and parts of the email based on business rules and then needs to update Grails domain objects and save those changes to the database.

Spring Integration service activator code snippet:

```
HashMap<String, Serializable> params = new HashMap<String, Serializable>();
params.put("notification", notification );
params.put("notificationType", notificationType );
params.put("sender", notificationSender );
InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(NotificationCreationService.class, "createNotification", params);
```

Grails NotificationCreationService action snippet:

```
def static createNotification() {
    if (params.notification != null && params.notificationType != null && params.sender != null) {
        String notification = params.get("notification") as String
        NotificationType notificationType = params.get("notificationType") as NotificationType
        String sender = params.get("sender") as String

        def NotificationMessage notificationMessage = null
        notificationMessage = new NotificationMessage()
        notificationMessage.notification = notification
        notificationMessage.save(flush: true)
        ...
    }
}
```

`NotificationMessage` is a standard Grails domain class

Error generated:

```
org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: 
    groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: mycompany.pyproject.mypackage.NotificationMessage.save() is applicable for argument types: () values: []
    Possible solutions: save(), save(boolean), save(java.util.Map), wait(), any(), wait(long)
```

If I change `createNotification()` to not be `static` then I get the following:

```
org.springframework.integration.MessageHandlingException: 
    groovy.lang.MissingMethodException: No signature of method: static mycompany.pyproject.mypackage.NotificationCreationService.createNotification() is applicable for argument types: (java.util.HashMap) values: [...]       
    Possible solutions: createNotification(java.util.HashMap), createNotification(java.lang.String, napa.changedetection.alert.NotificationType, java.lang.String)
```

I've tried other combinations of `InvokeHelper.invokeMethod()` and the definitions of the Grails actions with similar results. `InvokeHelper` has several other methods for invoking methods as well as setting different properties, but I haven't found the magic combination to make this work and any internet searched have turned up very little as far as example code for InvokeHelper.

Ideally, the Grails action would not be static and it would use the standard `params` mechanism. This would allow me to call the same action directly from the Grails code as well as from the Spring Integration service activator via the `InvokeMethod` functionality.

Does anyone have any thought on how to tie this together?

Comment: I started down this path by following [How to access Grails domain classes in Java service layer?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717098/how-to-access-grails-domain-classes-in-java-service-layer)

Comment: I have no idea what you'd need to do to solve this, but I think the underlying problem is that you call the static service method fine, but the NotificationMessage class has not been decorated by GORM to have save methods, etc.  If I had to guess, I would say that your Spring code has a different version of NotificationMessage loaded in a different classloader to the one running Grails.  But this is a guess.

Comment: Basically... If I invoke the static action from the Java code, the params are read correctly, but the domain objects aren't decorated with the save() action. If I invoke the non-static action from the Java code, the params *are not* read correctly, but save() works as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should not use InvokeHelper now, Grails 2 injects signature at compile time for java purposes (except dynamic finders, but you can guess why).

In your Java bean I would inject notificationCreationService using :

- resources.groovy/xml + setter

  OR
- Constructor + applicationContext (implement ApplicationContextAware)

Using the service reference should work, if not there is a bug to analyse there.

Where did you declare your service activator ?

Comment: I import my `spring-integration-config.xml` in `applicationContext.xml` in the `web-app\WEB-INF` folder of my project. I spend most of my time in a straight Java environment and that's how I've set it up before. I'm new to Grails, so if there is a better way to declare the service activator in Grails, I'd be happy to learn it. :-)

Comment: Outstanding! This is exactly what I needed. Three days of beating my head against the wall solved with injecting a single property into my service activator. It's easy when you know how. :-)
I wound up having to move my Spring Integration configuration out of `web-app\WEB-INF` to `grails-app\conf\spring\resources.xml`. When it was in `web-app`, it couldn't locate the reference to the `notificationCreationService`. Thanks!