# Grails domain class method from java source error: cannot find symbol

Tags: java, grails, groovy

In my app I have a grails domain class Student. I also have a few classes in src.java originally written in plain java.

In one of those classes in some method I am trying to get a collection of students like this:

```
this.students = new ArrayList<Student>(Student.findAll());
```

Grails package is imported, intellij doesn't complain, however I get foolwing error while trying to compile.

```
[groovyc] org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
  [groovyc] Compile error during compilation with javac.
  [groovyc] F:\path\ProjectName\src\java\grb\StudentSchedule.java:58: error: cannot find symbol
  [groovyc]         this.students = new ArrayList<Student>(Student.findAll());
  [groovyc]                                                       ^
  [groovyc]   symbol:   method findAll()
  [groovyc]   location: class Student
```

I have been also trying different methods, on Student, but all give me the same error - cannot find symbol.

Comment: The method `findAll()` is dynamically added by Grails to all domain classes. So calling the method relies on Groovy's dynamic dispatch to find the method and then execute it. Because the method doesn't exist in the class itself, you can't call it directly from Java.

Comment: Emmanuel, thanks for the comment! Is there any way to workaround?

Comment: Write those classes in groovy instead of Java

Comment: Which version of Grails are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As the [Grails docs](https://grails.github.io/grails-doc/latest/guide/GORM.html) state: ***You can also write Grails domain classes in Java*** 
You have to use *org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper* from Java
For more information see this [mailing list](http://grails.1312388.n4.nabble.com/Calling-Dynamic-Finders-on-Domain-Class-via-the-MetaClass-td1596496.html) 
Kind of **sample code**:

```
import my.package.User
import org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.InvokerHelper;

List allInstances = (List)InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(User.class, "list", null)); 

User one=(User)InvokerHelper.invokeMethod(User.class, "get", id);
```

maybe [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2717098/how-to-access-grails-domain-classes-in-java-service-layer) can help as well. 
But I would agree on the idea of writing the classes in Groovy.

Comment: Thank you Mikelis! That is what I ended up doing, and it worked!